# How can I call ToLower() on each string in a collection using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my query:

```
m_SelectedHandler = m_ListOfHandlers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.CountryNames.Contains(country.ToLower());
```

`country` is a string and an argument to the method containing the assignment above.  `CountryNames` is a list of strings.  How can I call `ToLower` on each of the strings in `CountryNames` so that I'll get valid matches for this query.  Is there a better way to do a case-insensitive compare using LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can specify an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) method.  For example, you could use [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase.aspx):

```
m_SelectedHandler = m_ListOfHandlers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.CountryNames.Contains(country, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This also avoids the temporary strings created by calling `ToLower`.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
m_ListOfHandlers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.CountryNames.Exists(cn => cn.ToLower() == country.ToLower());
```

Comment: Using ToLower for case-insensitive comparison == fail. http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.Any` like this:

```
m_SelectedHandler = m_ListOfHandlers
    .SingleOrDefault(h => h.CountryNames
        .Any(countryName => countryName.ToLower() == country.ToLower()));
```

or replace `==` with `.Equals like so:

```
countryName.Equals(country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

to do a case-insensitive match

Answer (score 0):

You could do `h.CountryNames.Any(x => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(x, country)`